# ci_last_regenerate overwritting session of codeigniter that is inside of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I recently put the codeigniter inside of wordpress, it takes a while until I can get it to work, but now that it is working it apparently does not work the sessions, and when I have to show the session variables it shows just this:

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1519649578 )
```

Here is what my wordpress public_html folder looks like:

```
-wp-content
-wp-includes
-wp-admin
-codeigniter
```

Here is my codeigniter config of sessions:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session_';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'ci_cache';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Then i set the $data on my login controller:

```
$this->load->library('session');

$data = {
            'logged_in' => true;
        }
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Finally when I try to receive this information from my other controller "users", it shows that result up:

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

PS: was working before I switched to WordPress

Comment: _“I recently put the codeigniter inside of wordpress”_ - first of all, _why_, and second of all, what does that even mean …?

Comment: Why bastardise two good systems? Depending on your needs just use one or the other. Combing them will only ever cause you issues as they are not designed to work together...

Comment: @CBroe means that i put ci in a folder inside wp, like i changed ^, and then changed .htaccess,they work like: https://wordpress/codeigniter